# How can I solve this Problem on ApexCharts with Angular 14?

Tags: angular, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I install the latest version of apexcharts in my project (Angular 14), and when I run the "ng serve", this error appeared in the console

Error: node_modules/ng-apexcharts/lib/chart/chart.component.d.ts:58:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments.

```
58     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<ChartComponent, "apx-chart", never, { "chart": "chart"; "annotations": "annotations"; "colors": "colors"; "dataLabels": "dataLabels"; "series": "series"; "stroke": "stroke"; "labels": "labels"; "legend": "legend"; "markers": "markers"; "noData": "noData"; "fill": "fill"; "tooltip": "tooltip"; "plotOptions": "plotOptions"; "responsive": "responsive"; "xaxis": "xaxis"; "yaxis": "yaxis"; "forecastDataPoints": "forecastDataPoints"; "grid": "grid"; "states": "states"; "title": "title"; "subtitle": "subtitle"; "theme": "theme"; "autoUpdateSeries": "autoUpdateSeries"; }, {}, never, never, false, never>;
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried reinstall the apex, and I can't update the Angular version

Comment: There is a [very similar issue](https://github.com/apexcharts/ng-apexcharts/issues/279) posted on their repo.